# Exposing servlet-based web services using JAX-WS

Tags: java, spring

I expose my Spring service as JAX-WS that explains in this url section 21.5.5

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html

and first I create my service that extends `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` and deploy war file, and again I eliminate extend class and deploy again; both time work correctly, now I wonder that

1. What's the difference between two?
2. Which one is better?
3. What are the pros and cons about these two implementations?

Answer (score 1):

1) If you extend SpringBeanAutowiringSupport then youll be able to autowire your dependencies into your service.

2) Depends if you want to Autowire dependencies to that service

3) Same as 2)

Comment: As you can see in the document that I mentioned before, it said that "The AccountServiceEndpoint may derive from Spring's SpringBeanAutowiringSupport but doesn't have to since the endpoint is a fully Spring-managed bean here. This means that the endpoint implementation may look like as follows, without any superclass declared - and Spring's @Autowired configuration annotation still being honored" and I test both of them, and both of inject class properly.